# Disable mongoldb health indicator Micronaut

Tags: java, kotlin, frameworks, jvm, micronaut

i want to disable health indicator for Micronaut, mi application cannot check the health for db. Im using Micronaut framework.
disable health indicator im getting the

`````
Path Taken: new HealthMonitorTask(CurrentHealthStatus currentHealthStatus,[List healthIndicators]) --> new MongoHealthIndicator(BeanContext beanContext,[HealthAggregator healthAggregator],MongoClient[] mongoClients)````

Do you know how to disable health but without getting this error?
`````

Comment: i disable the endpoint helcheck with ```endpoints:
  health:
    enabled: false``` but still getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to replace the implementation with one that always returns `UP`:

```java
@Singleton
@Requires(beans = MongoClient.class)
@Replaces(MongoHealthIndicator.class)
public class MyMongoHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Publisher<HealthResult> getResult() {
        return Publishers.just(buildStatus("mongodb"));
    }

    private HealthResult buildStatusUp(String name) {
        HealthResult.Builder builder = HealthResult.builder(name);
        builder.status(HealthStatus.UP);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```